# MergeAdapterDemo crashing when making call to addView()

Tags: android, merge, crash, adapter

I am attempting to run commonsguy's MergeAdapterDemo.  The code compiles and runs fine when i comment out the calls to addView.  For example, this runs fine:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    adapter=new MergeAdapter();
    arrayAdapter=buildFirstList();
    adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //adapter.addView(buildButton(), true);
    adapter.addAdapter(buildSecondList());
    //adapter.addView(buildLabel());
    adapter.addAdapter(buildSecondList());
```

However, this will crash:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    adapter=new MergeAdapter();
    arrayAdapter=buildFirstList();
    adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    adapter.addView(buildButton(), true);
    adapter.addAdapter(buildSecondList());
    adapter.addView(buildLabel());
    adapter.addAdapter(buildSecondList());
```

Here is the callstack when the crash occurs:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NoClassDefFoundError))  
    MergeAdapter.addViews(List, boolean) line: 101  
    MergeAdapter.addView(View, boolean) line: 78    
    MergeAdapter.addView(View) line: 64 
    MergeAdapterDemo.onCreate(Bundle) line: 52  
    Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1611    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1663 
    ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 931   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I am using the prebuilt .jar file that was located in the download section of his page.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 101 is

```
 addAdapter(new SackOfViewsAdapter(views));
```

But you don't have `SackOfViewsAdapter` class.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/blob/master/README.markdown says that:

> This project requires the CWAC SackOfViewsAdapter. A copy of a
>   compatible JAR can be found in the libs/ directory of the project,
>   though you are welcome to try newer ones, or ones that you have
>   patched yourself.

So you need to include that library in your project as well.

Comment: You were absolutely correct.  I figured it would be included in the jar for the MergeAdapter.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Post your layout XML file here.

Also check if you are using `MergeAdapter` tag properly in XML.